# Como digitar diretamente as casas decimais após o usuário digitar vírgula com Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou desenvolvendo um site web usando javascript/jquery e em alguns campos o usuário digita valores númericos. Alguns desses campos, por necessidades do negócio, possuem 9 casas decimais:

> 0,00000000

Meu problema é que, num caso assim, para digitar, por exemplo, 50,00000, o usuário necessita digitar 5 e então vários zeros até que o 5 esteja no seu local correto.

Minha dúvida: como eu faço para que o usuário, ao pressionar vírgula, já consiga digitar as casas decimais diretamente, sem precisar preencher com vários zeros até formar o número que ele deseja?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independente da forma que você está montando a sua máscara, uma opção simples é inicializar o valor do campo:

```js
$("#js").on("keyup", function(ev){
  if (ev.keyCode == 110 || ev.keyCode == 188){
    var valor = $("#js").val();
    $("#js").val( valor + "00000000");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Simples: <input value="00,00000000" />
<br><br>
Com JS: <input id="js" />
```